# How to remove the Plugins Editor from the admin menu

Tags: admin-menu

I have the code to remove the editor from the Appearance menu. But I can't find anyway to remove the editor from the Plugins.

```
    // Remove Editor from Apperance Menu
function remove_editor_menu() {
  remove_action('admin_menu', '_add_themes_utility_last', 101);
    }
add_action('_admin_menu', 'remove_editor_menu', 1);
```

Comment: Friendly reminder to update your question with more info or select a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way would be to use the disallow file editing constant in your config file.

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_the_Plugin_and_Theme_Editor

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go,

```
   function my_remove_menu_elements()
    {
        remove_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'plugin-editor.php' );
    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_elements');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function remove_plugin_editor()
    {
        remove_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'plugin-editor.php' );
    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'remove_plugin_editor');
```

for more information on it visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

Comment: Mohit, this should have been simply an amendement to Wyck's answer... Yours is one and a half hours after his and there's no problem editing someone else's answer. Kind regards :)