# Alternatives to DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT wp-config Constant? It Breaks Some Plugins

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, wp-config

#### The Problem

I first noticed this with the plugin Quick-Cache, which activates without problem, but doesn't shows up anywhere. Its menu it's simply not there. Found why, and became aware of the conflict, [in the forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-quick-cache-a-wp-super-cache-alternative-definedisallow_file_edit-true-kills-the-plugin).

Problem is that the plugin does all the capability checking using `edit_plugins`, removed by the constant...

Now I found that the plugin Search and Replace also bugs with the constant.
[image]

#### The solution

I just added this information to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_the_Plugin_and_Theme_Editor).

And would like to search for alternatives to enabling DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT.

Filtering the `map_meta_cap`, obviously, doesn't works.
What I can think of is removing the [submenu item](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/31165/12615), the action link and, case someone lands in `/plugin-editor.php` by a direct URL, make the editor window read-only.

I already assembled this code and will post as an answer, but would be glad to know this community opinion and other possible approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this would be of better use as a `mu-plugin`.

**EDIT:** Now available as drop & play MU-Plugin. Also disables the »Theme« editor.

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/** Plugin Name: Disable »Theme/Plugin Editor« */


if ( ! class_exists( 'disable_admin_editor' ) )
{
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'disable_admin_editor', 'init' ) );

class disable_admin_editor
{
    public static $instance;

    public static function init()
    {
        null === self :: $instance AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        ! defined( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT' ) AND define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );

        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'remove_edit_submenu' ) );
        add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', array( $this, 'remove_edit_action' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'admin_footer-plugin-editor.php', array( $this, 'readonly_textarea' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Remove Edit submenu
     */
    public function remove_edit_submenu()
    {
        remove_submenu_page( 'plugins.php', 'plugin-editor.php' );
        remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' );
    }

    /**
     * Remove the »Edit« link from all plugins
     * @param  array  $links
     * @param  string $file
     * @return array  $links
     */
    public function remove_edit_action( $links, $file ) 
    {
        unset( $links['edit'] );
        return $links;
    }

    /**
     * Makes the editor read-only and removes the Update button
     */
    public function readonly_textarea()
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $( "#newcontent" ).attr( "readonly", true );
            $( "input#submit" ).remove();
        } );     
        </script>';
    }
} // END Class 

} // endif;
```

Comment: The update I made has three(!!) ways to handle it. It's much too much, but better be on the safe side.

Comment: Hey, this is *Adding Class* to a rough idea in many many senses. (bow) `bloody cool, thx`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change this check via hook; but i will change this in a newxt version; I have see this problem for long time ago, but not enough time for an update. Yes, it is possible via constant, that you remove this right-capability and then it is not possible to use this plugin. I will ask for `manage_options`, but is not the best for this plugin, change hard on the tables and i think it is liek to an update capabilities; ther is also change it.

Comment: Yep, I see the point of *hard changes* in the database posed by Search-and-Replace... Maybe a good option would be checking for the capability and then checking if the constant is set, so we can filter the error message...

Comment: yes, its possible to check for the constant, if is true, then use an other capability.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise you can remove the other submenu via admin_init

```
remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' );
```